# String literal in select returns something different when using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the following script that I'm running in SSMS with Sql Server. I'm trying to find which columns in my table have "time" somewhere in the column name.

The first select shows which columns are available in the table being accessed.

The next two are my question. The first sets my variable @timeColumn to the string I'm looking for N'%time%' and the second uses the literal itself. I would expect these 2 selects to return the same column name but they don't. Any ideas why?

```
USE MyLargeDB
declare @tableName NVARCHAR(100), @timeColumn NVARCHAR(100), @foundTimeCol NVARCHAR(100)
Set @tableName = N'Faults'
SET @timeColumn = N'%time%'
SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE Name LIKE @timeColumn
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(@tableName)

SET @foundTimeCol = (SELECT top 1 Name
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE Name LIKE @timeColumn
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(@tableName))

print 'Found column with variable: ' + @foundTimeCol

SET @foundTimeCol = (SELECT top 1 Name
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE Name LIKE N'%time%'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(@tableName))
print 'Found column with literal string: ' + @foundTimeCol
```

The output: [image]
[image]

Comment: If you want the data to come back in a consistent order, you need to specify an Order By clause.  Otherwise there is no guarantee that SQL will give you the data in the same order every time (even if it looks like it usually does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using "TOP 1" in your SELECT which assumes the results are ordered.  Add "ORDER BY Name" to both SELECT TOP 1 statements to get the same results.  Of course this is only returning one of the possible matches.

Something like this:

```
SET @foundTimeCol = (SELECT top 1 Name
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE Name LIKE @timeColumn
  AND Object_ID = Object_ID(@tableName)
  ORDER BY Name)
```

Comment: I figured the ORDER BY would correct it, but I didn't understand why. So I guess I was just lucky that it returned the same values each time I ran it. Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: TOP 1 without an ORDER BY is undefined... it returns the first one found, and that can vary depending on the plan the SQL Server instance decides to use to satisfy your query, and that plan can vary from run to run, or with slight changes to the SQL itself.  WHENEVER you use "TOP", you ALWAYS need an "ORDER BY", or it's not deterministic.